# Attach metadata to existing fungible token

Tags: metaplex, metadata, fungible-token, spl-token

I have tried to use CreateMetadataV2 to attach the metadata to my token, but the token name, symbol and image is still not changed. The metadata is shown in Solana Explorer with no issue. Is there any extra steps required to update the metadata for existing FT tokens?

https://explorer.solana.com/address/7Wh4ALdTGJkSwCPrP9vFfywMxjDjgFPF4JmyJPLp7kSJ/metadata?cluster=devnet

Below is the json shown in Solana explorer under metadata tab.

```
    "root": {
        "key": 4,
        "updateAuthority": "7T3gmsvHY9EnF3ZEURjhQS4L5tEP1ySeXHkswYh4rFvz",
        "mint": "7Wh4ALdTGJkSwCPrP9vFfywMxjDjgFPF4JmyJPLp7kSJ",
        "data": {
            "name": "OTHERS",
            "symbol": "OTHERS",
            "uri": "https://x43oo5kgzwhqsnc2njsve5oyki5pbjomsufr453isefmen45.arweave.net/vzbndUbNjwk0Wmpl-UnXYUjrwp_cyVCx53aJEKwjeds",
            "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 1000,
            "creators": [
                0: {
                    "address": "7T3gmsvHY9EnF3ZEURjhQS4L5tEP1ySeXHkswYh4rFvz",
                    "verified": 1,
                    "share": 100,
                },
            ]
        },
        "primarySaleHappened": 0,
        "isMutable": 1,
        "editionNonce": 252,
        "tokenStandard": 2,
        "collection":undefined,
        "uses":undefined
    }
```

Code Snippet For CreateMetadataV2

```
   const metadataData = new DataV2({
        name: "OTHERS",
        symbol: "OTHERS",
        uri: "https://x43oo5kgzwhqsnc2njsve5oyki5pbjomsufr453isefmen45.arweave.net/vzbndUbNjwk0Wmpl-UnXYUjrwp_cyVCx53aJEKwjeds",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 1000,
        creators: [
            new Creator({
                address: secretJson.owner.pub_key,
                verified: true,
                share: 100
            }),
        ],
        collection: null,
        uses: null,
    });

    const mintPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(secretJson.token_address);
    const fromKeyPair = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(keyPairJson));
    const metadataPDA = await Metadata.getPDA(mintPublicKey);
    const createMetadataTx = new CreateMetadataV2(
        { feePayer: fromKeyPair.publicKey },
        {
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            metadataData,
            updateAuthority: fromKeyPair.publicKey,
            mint: mintPublicKey,
            mintAuthority: fromKeyPair.publicKey,
        } as any
    );


    let signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createMetadataTx, [fromKeyPair]);
```

Comment: Which name and symbol are you trying to set it to? When I open the link you provided I see "WORKS" as the symbol, did you want it to be "OTHER"?

Comment: Also, any chance you could share a code snippet of the createMetadadaV2 function call?

Comment: @JoeC Yes, I am going to set the name and symbol into "OTHERS". The code snippet is updated to the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you have to pass createMetadataTx.instructions to the sendAndConfirmTransaction function.